# Replacing ASP.NET to VueJs & Dreamfactory

Tags: asp.net, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, dreamfactory

I am an asp.net `web-forms` guy, this is a few years I am developing a web application with asp.net. Just I got a project called "Human Resources Management System" and I wanted to do this project with some new technology.

One of my friends advised me to do it with VueJs + Dreamfactory, which is very light-weight and can do more thing with simple ways.

Now I am stacked between these two options if anyone of you can give me advice whether to choose VueJs + Dreamfactory (Dreamfactory for back-end API) or should I go with my old ASP.NET webforms. I am afraid and didn't know if this VueJs + Dreamfactory could be enough for a project like HRMS (Human Resources Management System) or not?

Comment: This question will likely get closed as off topic. FWIW, I've never heard of DreamFactory. Vue integrates pretty easily with ASP.NET.

Comment: You can use asp.net to build your backEnd API, this way you'll need to learn only vue.js

Comment: StackOverflow is about solving problems, not discussing possibilities, your question will probably be deleted. I think Reddit would be a better place to ask such questions.